# Unable to download sources, javadoc in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_927fef28-7488-4483-9527-5596851d39e8'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1@aar.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I am unable to download sources for any of the library, once I click on download sources, I get the above error.

(Note : None of the existing answers worked for me, either they are obsolete (or) had some other error.)

Comment: Even I am facing the same error. This is happening only to google libraries other libraries are working fine